# Read session from parent directory

Tags: php, http, session, cookies

In http://myDomain.com/directory_1/index.php, I used `session_start()` to create a session.

Then, in http://myDomain.com/directory_2/index.php, I used `session_start()` to create a session.

Now, in http://myDomain.com/index.php, I would like to access all sessions which are tied to any sub-directory.

How is this done?

**EDIT** I am sorry, I just realized when originally creating a session in directory_1/index.php and directory_2/index.php, I did so as follows:

```
$cookie_domain=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (substr($cookie_domain, 0, strlen('www.')) == 'www.') {$cookie_domain = substr($cookie_domain, strlen('www.'), strlen($cookie_domain) );} //remove leading www (if exists)
$cookie_domain='.'.$cookie_domain;    //Add . wildcard
$cookie_path=dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/';
session_set_cookie_params(0, $cookie_path,$cookie_domain);
session_start();
```

Comment: Use session_start() as this is required on each page that uses session variables (regardless of where they are created within the site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path of the session cookie is `/`, so (unless you've changed this) you'll be able to access the same session regardless of directory by putting `session_start()` at the top of `/index.php`.

Comment: Your statement "unless you've changed this" seems to have been my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add:

> session_start()

at the top of your page(index.php) and then you will be to able access `$_SESSION` variables declared anywhere(outside directory).